# Nested IF Functions in Excel not working

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have quite a large excel document that has a good amount of vlookups, if functions, etc. In some of my tabs I cannot get my IF Functions to work and I have checked my logic 10 times over. I can't seem to figure out why excel is stopping at a certain condition and not checking the rest of my nests. Here's what a sample of the data looks like

```
      AE            AI           AL           AM           AN
DateResolved    DateCreated Response Time   Dummy   Response Time Bucket
    1/7/2016    1/1/2016     6                -         0-7 
    1/18/2016   1/3/2016     15               -         15-30 
    1/25/2016   1/4/2016     21               -         15-30 
    1/25/2016   1/4/2016     21               -         15-30 
    1/25/2016   12/31/2015   25               -         15-30 
    NULL        1/4/2016     Outstanding >30  1         >30 
    NULL        1/4/2016     Outstanding >30  1         >30 
    1/26/2016   1/4/2016     22               -         15-30 
    NULL        1/4/2016     Outstanding >30  1         >30
```

I'm taking DateResolved - (MINUS) DateCreated to get a Response Time. This Response time has this nested IF Function:

```
   =IF(AE2="NULL",IF(MAX(AI:AI)-AI2>30,"Outstanding >30","Outstanding <30"),AE2-AI2)
```

Which is great, because it did what I wanted it to. Outstanding >30 days shows up in column AL(the max date in DATE CREATED is sometime in July, but it's truncated, that's why the IF statement is satisfied when DateResolved = NULL , max DateCreated - DateCreated > 30, Response Time is returned as "Outstanding >30".

The problem lies in column AN - Response Time Bucket. Here's the formula:

```
=IF(AL2<=7,"0-7",IF(AL2<=14,"8-14",IF(AL2<=30,"15-30",IF(AL2>30, ">30",IF(AL2="Outstanding >30",AL2," Outstanding <30")))))
```

I simply just want AN to return "Outstanding >30" when AL is "Outstanding >30" and to return "Outstanding <30" when AL is "Outstanding <30". The formula seems to stop AFTER the fourth nest, and lumps my "Outstanding" Response times into ">30", which I DO NOT want.

I've tried this many different ways. First I substituted AL2 in the last nest for "Outstanding >30". I also tried creating a dummy in column AM where the formula is =if(AL2="Outstanding >30",1,0) and then substituting that into column AN. I set my last nest as IF(AM2=1,"Outstanding >30","Outstanding <30"). It still didn't work. It is STILL quitting after the 4th nest and saying ">30". I even tried to take the numbers out and replaced "Outstanding >30" in column AL with OST and substituting "OST" into my formula so that the excel is not mistakenly reading the last bit of "Outstanding >30".

UPDATE: I edited the formula to include ">30" as the last piece of my formula, i.e. it is what appears if the condition is FALSE. I'm not sure why it worked, but it does. Here it is:

```
=IF(O2<=7,"0-7",IF(O2<=14,"8-14",IF(O2<=30,"15-30",IF(O2="Outstanding >30","Outstanding >30",IF(O2="Outstanding <30","Outstanding <30",">30")))))`
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that

```
"Outstanding >30">30
```

is evaluating to `TRUE`.

For whatever reason, it appears that Excel treats text as greater than any number value when doing a comparison like this.

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize your formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(AL2),IF(AL2<=7,"0-7",IF(AL2<=14,"8-14",IF(AL2<=30,"15-30",">30"))),AL2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand how Excel handles text (including text that contains numbers).  When you compare the value "Outstanding > 30" to any number, "Outstanding > 30" will always be higher.  In other words:

```
="Outstanding >30" > 999999
```

will output `TRUE`.

There are multiple ways to modify your formula to work.  I suggest you check if AL2 = "Outstanding >30" and "Outstanding <30" at the beginning of your formula before checking the number of days.

Here's a rework of your formula.  Notice use of the `OR` function.

```
=IF( OR( AL2="Outstanding >30", AL2="Outstanding <30" ), AL2, IF(AL2<=7,"0-7",IF(AL2<=14,"8-14",IF(AL2<=30,"15-30",IF(AL2>30, ">30",IF(AL2="Outstanding >30",AL2," Outstanding <30"))))))
```

Also, did you intend to include a blank space at the end of the formula?

```
..." Outstanding <30"
```

Lastly, you might consider adding a column that calculates the response time using numbers only (no text).  Even if you keep a column with text, you can use the underlying number to calculate that text.  Also, your formula might use the `TODAY()` function as the date resolved where the value is `NULL` if