# Excel CountIF nested in IF function

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a dashboard I'm trying to put together and I don't understand how Excel is interpreting my formulas. I'm trying to get excel to read a cell that contains a month value, and if that value is true, then to read my dummy variables and count them. There is multiple criteria here so I used CountIFS.

Here's how the function works

```
=IF('Other tab'!$AI:$AI=B3,COUNTIFS('Other tab'!$BI:$BI,1,'Other Tab'!$BB:$BB,1,'Other tab'!$BC:$BC,1),"ERROR")
```

where any place there is a "1" there was a dummy variable created. I also tried to do this with the actual text that the dummy variables replaced and my formula still wouldn't work. I don't get an error, but the return value is "0"

```
Here's a sample of the data:
Current Tab:
1      A        B        C        D      E       F   G       H
2
3   Metric  January February    March   April   May June    July

Other tab:
    AI              BB          BC              BI
1 January           0            1               1
2 January           0            1               1
3 January           0            0               0
4 January           1            1               1
5 January           1            1               1
6 December          1            1               1
```

According to my formula, "3" should be the result here.

**Update: I switched the formula to read the "0"'s on my dummy variables instead of the "1"'s and it worked to retrieve that, so why isn't it working when specifying "1" as my countif criteria?**

Comment: Are the month names on both the same?  What I mean is there is two ways to get the month.  One is to have a literal text string `January`.  The second is a date that is formatted `mmmm`.  Are both tabs the same type?  If not you are trying to compare a number to text and will never match.

Comment: And it should only be `2` as there are only 2 rows where all three are `1` and the month is January.

Comment: Also did any of the answers in  your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415448/nested-if-functions-in-excel-not-working work for you?  If not then please give feed back so we can adjust to answer the question.  If so please mark the one that worked as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.  You will start seeing less people willing to help if no feedback is given.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to put the first part in an IF statement just add it as criteria to the COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS('Other tab'!$AI:$AI,B3,'Other tab'!$BI:$BI,1,'Other Tab'!$BB:$BB,1,'Other tab'!$BC:$BC,1)
```

[image]

---

It appears that your data not consistent.  You are looking for a text string in a series of dates that is formatted `mmmm`.  To deal with this, in another column on the `Other tab` put this formula:

```
=TEXT(AI1,"mmmm")
```

And copy down.

Then change the `'Other tab'!$AI:$AI` part in the above formula to new column in which you just put the 2nd formula.

This will now allow the comparison of text to text.

Comment: I believe I had that formula formatted this way last week, and it wouldn't work either so I switched it around and got this. I'll try to and post my results

Comment: I changed it to this and got "0", even when my criteria was either 0 or 1. The other formula worked when i switched the criteria is "0".

Comment: You need to show your data.  There is something missing in your explanation.

Comment: The formula I gave works for me see edit.  And see my comment above as to why yours is not working.